# x2go compresses multiple remote monitors into one window

Tags: xrandr, x2go

I am trying to connect to a local session on a remote Linux machine which has two physical monitors attached. My local x2go client is a Windows machine with only one monitor. When I connect, the content of both remote monitors (since they are only recognized as one display :0)  gets squeezed into one window. This means its either highly distorted (if I just full screen it) or too small to be of any use (if I try to adjust the window size for the correct aspect ratio).

Is there any way to "split up" a remote dual monitor display and choose between the screens on the client side?

Comment: I have the same problem (only connecting from Linux to Linux). Remote two monitors are sqeezed into one local monitor and I can see nothing. Anybody knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, I found a working solution:

First you have to switch from x2go's integrated X-server to an external one in the  "configuration > X.org-Server configuration" tab. In my case, this would be Xming, since I am on a Windows client. For a linux system, this should work with any X version (not tested).

You then have to add the command line options `-scrollbars -screen 0 <width of both monitor screens combined> <height of screens>`.

If you then restart x2go, it should load an X-server window of the size that you specified and with scrollbars allowing you to "switch" between monitors. Not ideal, but I believe that's as good as it gets. If you now connect to your double monitor remote, both monitors should be able to fit into this window undistorted.

Comment: where have found that option? x2goclient has no such command line option and googling the cmdline options this page is the only hit... Unfortunately I can not recreate your workaround.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I have since then switched to NoMachine for remote desktop on my Linux machine, which works flawlessly.

Comment: @HorrorVacui, see x2go client menu Options - x.org server settings - command line options